# Retrieve data from firebase in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5rsJ.png)How to **retrieve** data from **firebase database** and how to assign that values to variables in **react native**

How can I get these two values into variables using simple way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the firebase docs are pretty good and give a good explanation of how to use it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

To be short:

- once you have specified a reference, ex. `let users = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId)`, you can read the data either once using the `.once()` method or add a listener for changes in the data using `on()`.
- You receive a snapshot from either of these methods, and need to call `snapshot.val()` to retrieve the data.
- Simply assign the snapshot.val() to a variable declared outside of the reading method, and you're good to go.

You can also reference a simple project I made using React-Native and firebase here: https://github.com/liplylie/rnChallenge

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @KrishanDKM no problem! Can you please mark this as correct as well?

Comment: Rong mark dont click he was going Web Not a Android